# codeclimate javascript duplications in object keys

Tags: javascript, code-duplication, code-climate

I am trying to make CodeClimate happy but it detects duplication inside in object: https://codeclimate.com/github/FNNDSC/vjs/src/helpers/helpers.lut.js

```
  static presetLuts() {
    return {
      'default':      [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]],
      'spectrum':     [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0.1, 0, 0, 1], [0.33, 0, 1, 1], [0.5, 0, 1, 0], [0.66, 1, 1, 0], [0.9, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]],
    Duplication
      'hot_and_cold': [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0.15, 0, 1, 1], [0.3, 0, 1, 0], [0.45, 0, 0, 0], [0.5, 0, 0, 0], [0.55, 0, 0, 0], [0.7, 1, 1, 0], [0.85, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]],
      'gold':         [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0.13, 0.19, 0.03, 0], [0.25, 0.39, 0.12, 0], [0.38, 0.59, 0.26, 0], [0.50, 0.80, 0.46, 0.08], [0.63, 0.99, 0.71, 0.21], [0.75, 0.99, 0.88, 0.34], [0.88, 0.99, 0.99, 0.48], [1, 0.90, 0.95, 0.61]],
      'red':          [[0, 0.75, 0, 0], [0.5, 1, 0.5, 0], [0.95, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]],
      'green':        [[0, 0, 0.75, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 1, 0], [0.95, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]],
      'blue':         [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0.5, 0, 0.5, 1], [0.95, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
    };
  }
```

How can I fix this type of duplications?

Best,